# Local port access blocked by iptables

Tags: linux, security, iptables, hardening

Although experienced with Linux, I'm new to `iptables`, having set it up following a Rackspace virtual server setup guide.

Using port scans and checking *remote* access to required ports, I can see all traffic is being blocked except for the ports I've specifically opened up.

However *I can't access ports I've opened up locally* (e.g. `w3m http://localhost:4848`).

Here are my `iptables` rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Tue Oct  7 20:06:11 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [44:3960]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [184:19472]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4848 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct  7 20:06:11 2014
```

As dumped by `sudo iptables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 45 packets, 4050 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  106 10697 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    64 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4848
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 77 packets, 9149 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

More output as requested in comments:

```
$ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24 brd XXX.XXX.XXX.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/19 brd XXX.XXX.XXX.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I suspect the lack of local access to these ports as the underlying cause of `glassfish` not working properly.

So my questions are:

- How can I open up local access to these ports, without compromising remote security?
- Are there any other recommended changes you would make to improve security?

Comment: Could you replace the `iptables -L` output above with that of `iptables -L -n -v`?  The interface information is crucial, and the packet counts it gives are also helpful in these cases.

Comment: On which "interface" are they bound ? What's your routing table ?

Comment: also add detail on your network setings; "ip link show" "ip addr show" (or ifconfig)

Comment: Interesting. Try to add `iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`. But also paste info other users have requested here.

Comment: Thanks guys - I've updated the question with the requested info.

Comment: @Glueon: `sudo iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` does indeed fix it. Is that a permanent solution, or more of a diagnostic step?

Comment: No, that's a normal practice to allow connections to your loopback device via separate rule. But I am confused why your existing rules drop the connection. You can remove my rule and readd it with the `LOG` action or `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG` and have a look in `dmesg` what packets are being dropped. What criteria is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find out what rules are you missing it is convenient to set a logging rule at the end of chain.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
```

You'll see in a `dmesg` output all the packets that reached the end of INPUT chain a then got dropped because of your DROP policy.
As I said in comments you are maybe missing a rule for your loopback device:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

But try to add a logging rule to find out a more concrete criteria for iptables.